# How apps that are loaded within iframes can send messages to each other

Tags: node.js, iframe

I have 2 apps, each has its own html, js, css, etc . .
I have another app which loads the two apps from within iframes.
for example:

```
another-app.html:
<iframe src='app1.html' >
<iframe src='app2.html' >
```

---

### and I also have a SDK which is written in plain JS where each one of the apps can use this SDK.js.

The goal is to send messages from one app to another via the SDK. what are my options ?
keep in mind the more than one instance of a specific app can be used and each instance (user) should have its own data id

Comment: Will these apps all be under the same origin ie. will the browser address bar be the same domain for app1.html and app2.html?

Comment: not necessarily, but let's assume that yes for the purpose of simplicity